# How to use allow only POST in Django REST API Viewset

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I went through the django rest framework documentation on Viewsets and dont seem to understand how to allow only POST requests on the browser API.

> Viewset

```
class EmailViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Email.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = serializers.EmailSerializer
```

> Model

```
class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

> Serializer

```
class EmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Email
        fields = ["email"]
```

Answer (score 2):

from . import models, serializers
from rest_framework import mixins

```
class EmailViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,mixins.CreateModelMixin,):
        queryset = models.Email.objects.all() 
        serializer_class = serializers.EmailSerializer


        def create(self,request):
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: you do not need to implement `create`, but you need to change the order of inheritance. See the example I am pointing to in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Viewsets are used together with a [router](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter) and, depending on what is being exposed in your viewset, various `GET` and `POST` will be created by the Django REST framework automatically.

Your `EmailViewSet` is a [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset), and exposes `.list()` (), `.retrieve()`, `.create()`, `.update()`, `.partial_update()`, and `.destroy()`, through inheritance. All those actions are `GET` and `POST` either at the `{prefix}/` and `{prefix}/{url_path}/` of your router.

If you want to narrow the set of actions, you should derive `EmailViewSet` from specific `mixins` that are limiting the actions of the viewset, for instance (see [this example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#example_3)):

- [CreateModelMixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#createmodelmixin) will be a `POST` on `{prefix}/`
- [UpdateModelMixin](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin) will be a `POST` on `{prefix}/{url_path}/`

Comment: i tried using the create model mixin but faced some error saying the router expected some parameters

can you help with a snippet for using the model and other details in the question@Raffi

Comment: @namdi Do not forget to add `viewsets.GenericViewSet` in addition to the `CreateModelMixin` as shown in the example.